# JQuery - Fetching a URL that returns 404 on first few fetches, then returns 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, download, parsing

Fetch a URL - mywebiste.com/blah.php --> returns 404

Fetch a URL - mywebsite.com/blah.php --> returns 404

Fetch a URL - mywebsite.com/blah.php --> returns 404

Fetch a URL - mywebsite.com/blah.php --> returns 200 // how do I loop until this the URL returns 200?

Previously phrased:

So I have a URL (foo) that I need to download after my page has finished rendering or the 
element that I want to show it in is on the page i.e. I'll call this function that I'm asking about from my element.

The problem is I have to keep downloading the URL until it returns 200, it starts of saying 404, and gives 200 and a bunch of other headers, once it's done.

Can anyone think of a quick and easy way of doing this? I'm sort of brain-dead @ 2:50AM :(

Comment: Go to sleep, maybe tomorrow morning you can rephrase that. You can't program when you're brain-dead anyway...

Comment: What do you mean by downloading a URL? What kind of a resource is it? Is it a file or html content?

Comment: it would help to see the code you are using to call the element.. Do you want to redirect/download a file or make an ajax call to just get an element of the page

Comment: <div id="myDiv"><script type="text/javascript">$fetchUrlUntilSuccess('mywebsite.com/blah.php');</script></div>

Comment: Please also answer my previous question. What kind of a resource do you want to fetch? Is it html content that you want to display in your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this - load the page, and try again and again on error. Make sure to add the rest of the arguments to `ajax`. You can add a check to load only on error code 404:

```
function tryLoad
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        success: function(data){ /* handle load */ },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(tryLoad, 1000); //try again later
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, this will load indefinitely if you have a real error.

Comment: trying this out, looks promising will mark as answer if it works!